# Notes Registration: how to create replica mail during Registration using lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Customer have two mail server which are:

**mailsvr1/bdy**

**mailsvr2/bdy**

**Question**: Customer wish to use an application to register notes account. Currently i will be able to register an notes account with only 1 email account, i not sure how to create an replica mail to another server. But I go notesregistration there have a function of create replica mail to another server

[image: replica mail1]

[image: replica mail2]

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


    Print "Register user agent started....."

    Dim s As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, a As NotesAgent
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set a = s.Currentagent
    Set doc = s.Documentcontext     '   uidoc 

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument, body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim groups
    groups = Null 

    groups = group(groups,"Everyone")
'   groups = group(groups,"Sales & Marketing PR Approval Team")

    Dim certid As String            '   full path of cert id
    Dim certpasswd As String
    Dim OU As String
    Dim lastname As String
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim middleinit As String
    Dim usrIdpath As String
    Dim mailsvr As String
    Dim mailfile As String
    Dim userpasswd As String
    Dim internetpathLength As String
    Dim internetpath As String
    Dim remapuserID As String

    Dim depvw As NotesView, depdoc As NotesDocument
    Set depvw = db.Getview("Department sort by dept")
    Set depdoc = depvw.Getdocumentbykey(doc.Dept(0), True)
    If Not depdoc Is Nothing Then
        certid = depdoc.IdPath(0)               '   full path of cert id
        certpasswd = depdoc.IdPassword(0)       '   Cert id password(password)
        OU = "" 'depdoc.Dept(0)                 '   Application (department to register)
        lastname= doc.Name(0)                   '   current document selected mail (person)
        firstname = ""                          '   [din't used]
        middleinit = ""                         '   [din't used]
        usrIdpath = depdoc.DptIdStor(0) +doc.SelectMail(0)+ ".id"       '   user path

    '   remove "." replace with empty and remove the empty space
        remapuserID = remapChr(doc.SelectMail(0))   ' this is remapuserID

        mailsvr = depdoc.MailSvr(0)             '   mail svr

    '   Mail file name also cannot have . in between for example, mail/test1.apple, reason window not understand it 
        mailfile = depdoc.MailLocation(0)+ remapuserID          '   Mail\Person

        userpasswd= depdoc.UserPassword(0)                              '   User password
        internetpath = doc.SelectMail(0)+depdoc.InternetPath(0)         '   mail address
        internetpathLength = Len(depdoc.InternetPath(0))                '   not used
    End If

    Dim reg As New NotesRegistration

    Dim dt As Variant
    dt = DateNumber(Year(Today)+1, Month(Today), Day(Today))

    reg.RegistrationServer = mailsvr        '"mailsvr/bdy"
    reg.CreateMailDb = True                 '
    reg.CertifierIDFile = certid            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\office.id"
    reg.Expiration = dt
    reg.IDType = ID_HIERARCHICAL
    reg.MinPasswordLength = 1               ' password strength
    reg.IsNorthAmerican = True
    reg.OrgUnit = OU                        ' "" empty ..will just follow certid registration
    reg.RegistrationLog = "log.nsf"
    reg.UpdateAddressBook = True
    reg.Storeidinaddressbook = False
    reg.MailInternetAddress =  internetpath '"desmond@devsv1.pcs.com.my"
    reg.Shortname=doc.SelectMail(0)         '   'Set shortname          []
    reg.Mailowneraccess =2                      '   '[editor access]
    reg.Mailcreateftindex=True                  '   '[Indexing]
    '   "CN=Lotus Administrator/O=Notes85"
    reg.Mailaclmanager ="LocalDomainAdmins" '   'Add person into mail acl
    reg.Grouplist=groups                    '   'Everyone and allstaff


    Call reg.RegisterNewUser(lastname, _    ' last name
    usridpath, _                            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\ +name+.id"    ' file to be created
    mailsvr, _                              '"mailsvr/bdy"              ' mail server
    firstname, _                            '                                   ' first name
    middleInit, _                           '                                   ' middle initial
    certpasswd, _                           '"office"                           ' certifier password
    "", _                                   ' location field
    "", _                                   ' comment field
    mailfile, _                             '"mail\person.nsf"                 ' mail file
    "", _                                   ' Forwarding domain
    userpasswd, _                           '"password", _                   ' user password
    NOTES_DESKTOP_CLIENT)                   ' user type

    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim aclEntry As NotesACLEntry
    Dim dbUser As NotesDatabase
    Set dbUser = New NotesDatabase(mailsvr,mailfile)    '   mail/person.nsf
    Set acl = dbUser.aCL
    Set aclEntry = acl.Getentry( "LocalDomainAdmins" )
    If Not (aclEntry Is Nothing) Then
        aclEntry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP
        Call acl.Save()
    End If


Dim ndb As NotesDatabase  
    Dim viwUser As NotesView
    Dim docUser As NotesDocument
    Set ndb = New NotesDatabase( mailsvr, "names.nsf" )

    Print "Please wait ...... accessing address book"

    Set viwUser = ndb.GetView("People by Email")    
    Set docUser = viwUser.GetDocumentByKey(doc.SelectMail(0),True)
    Call docUser.ReplaceItemValue( "HTTPPasswordForceChange" , "1" )

    Print "Force user change password is updated"

    Call docUser.Save( True, True, True )   '   save the document   

    Print "Please wait ...... address book in been updated"


    Print "Register user agent ended....."
EndOfRoutine:
    Exit Sub 'or exit function
ErrorHandler:
    Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
    Resume EndOfRoutine
```

**New Script with add [Mailreplicaservers]**

```
Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Print "Register user agent started....."

    Dim s As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, a As NotesAgent
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set a = s.Currentagent
    Set doc = s.Documentcontext     '   uidoc 

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument, body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim groups
    groups = Null 

    groups = group(groups,"Everyone")
'   groups = group(groups,"Sales & Marketing PR Approval Team")

    Dim certid As String            '   full path of cert id
    Dim certpasswd As String
    Dim OU As String
    Dim lastname As String
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim middleinit As String
    Dim usrIdpath As String
    Dim mailsvr As String
    Dim mailsvr2 As string
    Dim mailfile As String
    'Dim mailfile2 As String
    Dim userpasswd As String
    Dim internetpathLength As String
    Dim internetpath As String
    Dim remapuserID As String

    Dim depvw As NotesView, depdoc As NotesDocument
    Set depvw = db.Getview("Department sort by dept")
    Set depdoc = depvw.Getdocumentbykey(doc.Dept(0), True)
    If Not depdoc Is Nothing Then
        certid = depdoc.IdPath(0)               '   full path of cert id
        certpasswd = depdoc.IdPassword(0)       '   Cert id password(password)
        OU = "" 'depdoc.Dept(0)                 '   Application (department to register)
        lastname= doc.Name(0)                   '   current document selected mail (person)
        firstname = ""                          '   [din't used]
        middleinit = ""                         '   [din't used]
        usrIdpath = depdoc.DptIdStor(0) +doc.SelectMail(0)+ ".id"       '   user path

    '   remove "." replace with empty and remove the empty space
        remapuserID = remapChr(doc.SelectMail(0))   ' this is remapuserID

        mailsvr = depdoc.MailSvr(0)             '   mail svr
        mailsvr2 = depdoc.MailSvr2(0)               '   mail svr
    '   Mail file name also cannot have . in between for example, mail/test1.apple, reason window not understand it 
        mailfile = depdoc.MailLocation(0)+ remapuserID          '   Mail\Person
    '   mailfile2 = depdoc.MailLocation2(0)+ remapuserID            '   Mail\Person
        userpasswd= depdoc.UserPassword(0)                              '   User password
        internetpath = doc.SelectMail(0)+depdoc.InternetPath(0)         '   mail address
        internetpathLength = Len(depdoc.InternetPath(0))                '   not used
    End If

    Dim reg As New NotesRegistration

    Dim dt As Variant
    dt = DateNumber(Year(Today)+1, Month(Today), Day(Today))

    reg.RegistrationServer = mailsvr        '"CN=ServerOne/O=dev"
    reg.Mailreplicaservers = mailsvr2
    reg.CreateMailDb = True                 '
    reg.CertifierIDFile = certid            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\office.id"
    reg.Expiration = dt
    reg.IDType = ID_HIERARCHICAL
    reg.MinPasswordLength = 1               ' password strength
    reg.IsNorthAmerican = True
    reg.OrgUnit = OU                        ' "" empty ..will just follow certid registration
    reg.RegistrationLog = "log.nsf"
    reg.UpdateAddressBook = True
    reg.Storeidinaddressbook = False
    reg.MailInternetAddress =  internetpath '"desmond@devsv1.pcs.com.my"
    reg.Shortname=doc.SelectMail(0)         '   'Set shortname          []
    reg.Mailowneraccess =2                      '   '[editor access]
    reg.Mailcreateftindex=True                  '   '[Indexing]
    '   "CN=Lotus Administrator/O=Notes85"
    reg.Mailaclmanager ="LocalDomainAdmins" '   'Add person into mail acl
    reg.Grouplist=groups                    '   'Everyone and allstaff

    '   reg.Mailreplicaservers

    Call reg.RegisterNewUser(lastname, _    ' last name
    usridpath, _                            '"C:\IBM\Domino\data\ +name+.id"    ' file to be created
    mailsvr, _                              '"CN=ServerOne/O=dev"               ' mail server
    mailsvr2, _                             '"CN=ServerTwo/O=dev"               ' replicate server
    firstname, _                            '                                   ' first name
    middleInit, _                           '                                   ' middle initial
    certpasswd, _                           '"office"                           ' certifier password
    "", _                                   ' location field
    "", _                                   ' comment field
    mailfile, _                             '"mail\person.nsf"                 ' mail file
    "", _                                   ' Forwarding domain
    userpasswd, _                           '"password", _                   ' user password
    NOTES_DESKTOP_CLIENT)                   ' user type

    Dim acl As NotesACL
    Dim aclEntry As NotesACLEntry
    Dim dbUser As NotesDatabase
    Set dbUser = New NotesDatabase(mailsvr,mailfile)    '   mail/person.nsf
    Set acl = dbUser.aCL
    Set aclEntry = acl.Getentry( "LocalDomainAdmins" )
    If Not (aclEntry Is Nothing) Then
        aclEntry.UserType = ACLTYPE_PERSON_GROUP
        Call acl.Save()
    End If


    Dim ndb As NotesDatabase  
    Dim viwUser As NotesView
    Dim docUser As NotesDocument
    Set ndb = New NotesDatabase( mailsvr, "names.nsf" )

    Print "Please wait ...... accessing address book"

    Set viwUser = ndb.GetView("People by Email")    
    Set docUser = viwUser.GetDocumentByKey(doc.SelectMail(0),True)
    Call docUser.ReplaceItemValue( "HTTPPasswordForceChange" , "1" )

    Print "Force user change password is updated"

    Call docUser.Save( True, True, True )   '   save the document   

    Print "Please wait ...... address book in been updated"


    Print "Register user agent ended....."
EndOfRoutine:
    Exit Sub 'or exit function
ErrorHandler:
    Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl
    Resume EndOfRoutine 
End Sub
```

**It give me an error on type missmatch , Type mismatch in line**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK: You found out about the "NotesRegistration" class...

The documentation of IBM (now HCL) is very good. Just check it for named class and you will find the Property [MailReplicaServers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_MAILREPLICASERVERS_PROPERTY_REG.html):

> **Defined in**
> NotesRegistration
>
> **Data type**
> Array of type String
>
> **Syntax**
> To get: variant = notesRegistration .MailReplicaServers
>
> To set: notesRegistration . MailReplicaServers = variant
>
> **Usage**
> Optionally set this property before calling RegisterNewUser.

Take care: MailReplicaServers is a VARIANT, it expects an array to be passed, not a single value. You could do either:

```
Dim mailservers(0) as String
mailservers(0)=mailsvr2 
reg.Mailreplicaservers = mailservers
```

or even easier from your second example:

```
reg.Mailreplicaservers = depdoc.MailSvr2
```

as depdoc.MailSvr2 already is an array with one entry.

Comment: it give me an error Type missmatch after i use mail replica server. script is reg.mailreplicaservers

mailsvr2 = depdoc.MailSvr2(0)    

reg.Mailreplicaservers = mailsvr2

Call reg.RegisterNewUser(lastname, _  
 usridpath, _  
 mailsvr, _   
 mailsvr2, _  
 firstname, _  
 middleInit, _
 certpasswd, _   
 "", _                               
 "", _                                
 mailfile, _   
 "", _                       
 userpasswd, _  
 NOTES_DESKTOP_CLIENT)

Comment: `Dim mailservers(0) as String mailservers(0)=mailsvr2 reg.Mailreplicaservers = mailservers`

Answer (score 0):

After user registration is complete, you can do one of the following:

1) Open the mail file and use the `NotesDatabase.CreateReplica` method

2) Use the `NotesAdministrationProcess.CreateReplica` method

Comment: cannot use lotus script [NotesRegistration] to direct create replica mail? Not sure how the process work?